# Time Zone Aware Date Facets in Solr

Tags: solr

I need to be able to return a series of Facet counts in solr, grouped by Date, and Time Zone aware. I can get groupings back by day, but when providing a timezone, it just alters the group so that all groups are no longer adjusted to the beginning of the day - they are just off by the time zone adjustment.  Which doesn't really provide the right information.

## I have the following Solr Query:

- facet.date.start=NOW/DAY-1DAY
- facet.date.end=NOW
- facet.date=auction_date_utc
- facet.date.gap=+1DAY

## GMT, How Delightful!

```
   "2015-08-12T00:00:00Z":1,
   "2015-08-13T00:00:00Z":3,
   "2015-08-14T00:00:00Z":2,
   "2015-08-17T00:00:00Z":2,
   "2015-08-18T00:00:00Z":6,
```

## LA Time Zone, So Sad.

When I add in the following parameter: ***TZ=America/Los_Angeles***

```
   "2015-08-12T07:00:00Z":1,
   "2015-08-13T07:00:00Z":3,
   "2015-08-14T07:00:00Z":2,
   "2015-08-17T07:00:00Z":2,
   "2015-08-18T07:00:00Z":6,
```

Am I missing some simple solution, or is this the best I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is returning precisely the data that is required. I thought I was seeing it *in the timezone I requested*, but what you get is in GMT - with an offset.  I was confused when I saw that the facet counts where the same between the two different selections.  Using an asian time zone shows that the counts are in fact different:

## For GMT:

```
"facet_dates":{
  "auction_date_utc":{
    "2015-07-17T00:00:00Z":3,
    "2015-07-20T00:00:00Z":10,
    "2015-07-21T00:00:00Z":18,
    "2015-07-22T00:00:00Z":6,
    "2015-07-23T00:00:00Z":4,
```

## For tz="Pacific/Apia"

```
"facet_dates":{
  "auction_date_utc":{
    "2015-07-17T11:00:00Z":3,
    "2015-07-19T11:00:00Z":1,
    "2015-07-20T11:00:00Z":10,
    "2015-07-21T11:00:00Z":20,
    "2015-07-22T11:00:00Z":3,
    "2015-07-23T11:00:00Z":5,
```